# Using manual explicit levels for overlay of tricontourf and scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap, levels, contourf

I'm trying to overlay a scatter plot (showing observations) onto a filled contour plot (showing model data for the same variable) using exactly the same levels for mapping onto che colorscale. The main problem is that I'm not using the "common" `contour`/`contourf` functions but `tricontourf`, since my data is on an unstructured grid.

It looks like some of the methods normally working on `contourf` are ignored by `tricontourf` and it's not the first time that I have to find a workaround, as options actually working with `tricontourf` are poorly documented (e.g. how to plot with missing values).

I want to plot accumulated precipitation. I have punctual data from stations and gridded data from the model. Both are 1-D arrays described by 1-D latitude and longitude arrays. I NEED to choose the same levels for both plots since I want to overlay them and see the differences. I'm using `pyplot.scatter` to plot the points and `pyplot.tricontourf` for the model data. Here are the approaches that I've used:

1. Define `vmin` and `vmax` for both `pyplot.scatter` and `pyplot.tricontourf` with the same cmap so that they are mapped with the same levels -> doesn't work as `pyplot.tricontourf` apparently ignores `vmin` and `vmax`. Following this example https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/tricontour_vs_griddata.html does NOT work for me. They are simply ignored and the levels are automatically defined.
2. Since the only way of specifying levels in `pyplot.tricontourf` is to use the `levels` argument I do so by defining an array of values. This works for `tricontourf` but then I have to map it for the scatter plot.

   ```
   levels=[10, 12, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 
           45, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250]
   contourf=plt.tricontourf(lon, lat, rain_acc, levels=levels, 
          cmap='GnBu', extend='max')

   bounds=np.array(levels)
   norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries=bounds, ncolors=256)

   scatter=plt.scatter(x, y, c=rain_stations, s=50, cmap='GnBu', 
       zorder=10, norm=norm)
   ```

   Unfortunately this does not work either, as `BounaryNorm` linearly interpolates between the levels.

So for now the only way I had to overlay the data was to choose a linear sequence of levels (defined with `np.linspace`) for `tricontourf` and then apply the method of point 2. to normalize the colors for the scatter plots.

[Here you can see the picture that I'm producing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hcCP.png)

However what I would like to do is to be able to define the levels manually.
Does anyone know how to achieve that?

And, most importantly, why are `vmin` and `vmax` ignored by `tricontourf`?

Comment: looking at the link you posted and the docs, `pyplot.tricontourf` doesnt seem to accept `vmin` and `vmax`. The way it was used in the example you posted is by using the `norm` argument: `plt.tricontourf(x, y, z,norm=plt.Normalize(vmax=abs(zi).max(), vmin=-abs(zi).max()))`

Comment: I have also done this, and it still didn't work. The levels were still set automatically.  By the way, nowhere on the documentation is said that `vmin` and `vmax` are ignored by `tricontourf`. I've found this on another question.